# How to get items from adapter and pass it in activity android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, retrofit, android-adapter

I am using `retrofit` where I have request in List type.

```
 public RequestBody(String msisdn, List<RoutePlanDayRequests> routePlanDayRequests ) {
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
        this.routePlanDayRequests = routePlanDayRequests;
    }
```

So this RoutePlanDayRequests has following pojo classes.

```
public class RoutePlanDayRequests {

    private String status;

    private String oldDay;

    private String neweDay;


    public String getOldDay() {
        return oldDay;
    }

    public void setOldDay(String oldDay) {
        this.oldDay = oldDay;
    }

    public String getNeweDay() {
        return neweDay;
    }

    public void setNeweDay(String neweDay) {
        this.neweDay = neweDay;
    }
}
```

So I am calling one web service to display the list in adapter.Now I am getting the response in adapter class and ***submit button in MainActivity.*** So when i change the spinner for other days and submit, how to get this items from adapter and pass the data in MainActivity?

Because in adapter class it has spinner where items get changed based on spinner selection. So those items when changed I need to submit. But problem is submit button is in MainActivity. So how to pass those item values in MainActivity?

MainActivity.class:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setcontentView(R.layout.main);

initialLoadingServiceList(); //this is to load initial items

 submitChangeRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //here I have been strucked.
                updateServiceList();
            }
        });

 private void updateServiceList() {
        List<RoutePlanDayRequests> request = null;
        //strucked to get the spinner values to pass in request.
        RetrofitInstance.getInstance(this)
                .create(RoutePlanService.class)
                .getSaveRoutePlanDay(new SaveDayRequest(new RequestBody("",request)) //here I need to pass the changed item values from adapter to here. 
    }
}

//Hope you got it my requirement. 

public void initialLoadingServiceList(){
//skipping service list.. 

    RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter adapter = new RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter(retailers, RoutePlanVisitChangeActivity.this);
                                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}


}
```

Adapter class:

```
public class RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter.RoutePlanVisitChangeView> {
    private List<Retailers> mList;
    private Context context;
    private String[] daysList = {"MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"};

    public RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter(List<Retailers> list, Context context) {
        this.mList = list;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public RoutePlanVisitChangeView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.route_plan_visit_change_row, parent, false);
        return new RoutePlanVisitChangeView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RoutePlanVisitChangeView holder, int position) {
        Retailers routePlanVisitChange = mList.get(position);
        holder.retailerName.setText(routePlanVisitChange.getName());
        holder.retailerNumber.setText(routePlanVisitChange.getMsisdn());
        holder.fromDay.setText(routePlanVisitChange.getRoutePlanDayOfWeek());
        String profileUrl = routePlanVisitChange.getProfileImage().getImageUrl();
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(profileUrl)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_profile)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_default_profile)
                .into((holder.profileImage));

        String getRoutePlanDay = routePlanVisitChange.getRoutePlanDayOfWeek().toUpperCase();
        List<String> asSet = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(daysList));
        asSet.remove(getRoutePlanDay);
        String[] newDayList = asSet.toArray(new String[]{});
        ArrayAdapter updatedData = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newDayList);
        updatedData.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.toDay.setAdapter(updatedData); //so now i changed the values in spinner. I need to update in button click in main activity
        String selectedSpinner = holder.toDay.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mList == null)
            return 0;
        return mList.size();
    }

    public class RoutePlanVisitChangeView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView retailerName;
        public TextView retailerNumber;
        public AppCompatButton fromDay;
        public Spinner toDay;
        public CircleImageView profileImage;

        public RoutePlanVisitChangeView(View view) {
            super(view);
            retailerName = (TextView) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_txt_acc_name);
            retailerNumber = (TextView) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_txt_acc_num);
            fromDay = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.from_day);
            toDay = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.to_day);
            profileImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_profile);
            //toDay = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.to_day);
        }
    }
    public Retailers getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
        }
     }
   }
```

Kindly suggest/ resolve my issue please. Struck badly how to get items in MainActivity from adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this approach**

> 1. Define one interface `RecyclerViewClickListener` for passing message from adapter to `Activity/Fragment`:

```
public interface RecyclerViewClickListener
{

     public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position);
     onSpinnerSelected(int position, Object selection);
}
```

> 2. In `Activity/Fragment` implement the `interface`, and also pass listener to adapter:

```
@Override
public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position){... ...}

//set up adapter and pass clicked listener this
myAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(context, this);
```

> 3. In Adapter and ViewHolder:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

   ... ... 
   private Context context;
   private static RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener;


   public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener) {

        this.context = context;
        this.itemListener = itemListener;
        ... ...
   }


   //ViewHolder class implement OnClickListener, 
   //set clicklistener to itemView and, 
   //send message back to Activity/Fragment 
   public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        ... ...

        public ItemViewHolder(View convertView)
        {
            super(convertView);
            ... ...

            convertView.setOnClickListener(this);
      //setting the listener in your spinner
       yourSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View container,
                int position, long id) {
            //here you have the position and spinner value selected just pass this to callback method.
            itemListener .onSpinnerSelected(getAdapterPosition(),spinner.getSelectedItem())
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
        }


       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
          itemListener.recyclerViewListClicked(v, this.getPosition());      

       }

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. If I want entire list? I don't want item click in recyclerview. Because for eg: it has 10 items and 10 spinner. So if I change 8th spinner, so in this case, I didn't clicked recyclerview. So entire items I need to update in submit button (which is in main activity). Hope you got it.

Comment: Add another method to interface implement it in mainactivity. when you change spinner invoke interface method

Answer (score 1):

**1:** make a **callback** listener and pass it to the **recyclerview** **adapter** class

```
public interface Callback{
    onSpinnerSelected(int position, Object selection);
}
```

**2:** now pass this to your adapter like this and give a reference of activity or fragment in which you are using it.

```
public class RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter.RoutePlanVisitChangeView> {
        private List<Retailers> mList;
        private Context context;
        private String[] daysList = {"MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"};
        private Callback callback;
        public RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter(List<Retailers> list, Context context, Callback callback) {
            this.mList = list;
            this.context = context;
            this.callback = callback;
        }
    //......
    }
```

**3:** and now when your spinner is selected just call this.

```
 public RoutePlanVisitChangeView(View view) {
        super(view);
        retailerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_txt_acc_name);
        retailerNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_txt_acc_num);
        fromDay = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.from_day);
        toDay = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.to_day);
        profileImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_profile);
        //toDay = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.to_day);

       //setting the listener in toDay spinner
       toDay.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View container,
                int position, long id) {
            //here you have the position and spinner value selected just pass this to callback method.
            callback.onSpinnerSelected(getAdapterPosition(),spinner.getSelectedItem())
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    }
```

**4:** now in your activity fragment where you have given the reference or initialized a constructor, you must overridden the callback methods.

```
public void initialLoadingServiceList(){
 //skipping service list.. 
 RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter adapter = new 
 RoutePlanVisitChangeAdapter(retailers, 
 RoutePlanVisitChangeActivity.this, new Callback(){
    @Override
    public void onSpinnerSelected(int position, Object selection){
        //here you use your selected value and cast it to particular object before use.
    }
});
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SelectAddressActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id", objects.getyourvariable());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about the important parts of your code?